# Zener VI Characteristics, noise reduction

Tags: zener, non-linear

[image]
Consider RIN = 1K, VI=9.5, vi=50m, given Zener characteristics by the graph. I have to find VO(DC output) and vo(small signal output.

Case 1: RL = 2k
for DC voltage :
`i = (9.5m - 3VO/2k)`, 
this is a linear load line, from this I assumed that zener could be operation in the middle region, i = 0, therefore VO = 6.33

for small signal `i = (50u - 3VO/2k)`even this falls under open circuit behaviour of zener diode.

based on this assumptions I am getting wrong answers, is there something that i am totalling misinterpreting.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you're misinterpreting pretty much everything. For VI voltages more than 5 volts, and RL large, your zener operates at the far left of the curve, and can be represented as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC0PbS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this only holds so long as the Thevenin equivalent of VI, R1 and RL is greater than the zener 5 volts.

R1, also called the zener dynamic resistance, is determined by the slope, in this case 1A/V. So your circuit looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffop3S.png)</sup>

Set the AC source to zero to find the DC output, then apply it to find the AC component.